# Disable the selection/touchdown menu in iOS

Tags: webview, react-native

I have a newbie React Native question. I am trying to use a WebView within a React View class but I am unable to get rid of the selection menu. I don't know if "selection menu" is the correct term, but it shows up when I press and hold down the mouse/finger.

I have tried browsing directly to the HTML page on an iPhone, and the "menu" does not pop up there.

React Native class:

```
var React = require('react-native');

var {
  WebView
} = React;

var TestWebView = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <WebView url="http://url/index.html" />
    );
  }
});

module.exports = TestWebView;
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        background: pink;
      }

      body {
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* mobile webkit */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result:

[image: The result]

If I remove the second styling block, I get the following result:

[image: Another result]

So it seems the styling has some effect but it does not completely remove it.

Any ideas?

I'm using React Native 0.11.4.